# Why were my questions on the subjunctive, and that on the gerund, closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/12287/5306 and https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/12279/5306 were closed because it is claimed:

> Language-specific grammar and usage questions are off-topic unless primarily concerned with linguistics rather than usage. ...

How are they language-specific? For instance, both the gerund and subjunctive figure in English and French and Spanish and many other languages, **but differently and disparately in each.**
I intended my questions to apply in general.

Comment: You're not asking about the subjunctive as a phenomenon, you're asking about the English word *subjunctive*, and I can't see anything of linguistic relevance in the question.